# Modify sign of Pandas dataframe's column based off another column's mask?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply, signed

I'm working with imported lat/lon data from NASA's fireball data API (https://cneos.jpl.nasa.gov/fireballs/)

- `lat`/`lon` data only have positive values
- their direction (N/S and E/W) are in different columns called `lat-dir`/`lon-dir`
- dataframe as below.
- Now I want to:
- **Convert any `lat` values to negative (multiply by -1) if "lat-dir" == 'S'**
- **Convert `lon` values to negative if "lon-dir" == 'W'**

Below is roughly how I created my dataframe:

```py
import requests 
import pandas as pd

response = requests.get('https://ssd-api.jpl.nasa.gov/fireball.api')
j = response.json()
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(j[u'data'])

print( j[u'fields'] )

[u'date', u'energy', u'impact-e', u'lat', u'lat-dir', u'lon', u'lon-dir', u'alt', u'vel']

print( df.head() )

0    1      2     3     4     5     6     7     8
0  2019-12-06 10:19:57  4.6   0.15   3.3     S  37.7     W  19.5  None
1  2019-12-03 06:46:27  4.2   0.14   5.6     N  52.2     W  61.5  None
2  2019-11-28 20:30:54  2.7  0.095  35.7     N  31.7     W    35  13.0
3  2019-11-28 13:22:10  2.6  0.092  None  None  None  None  None  None
4  2019-11-28 11:55:02  2.5  0.089  22.1     S  25.7     E  22.5  24.7
```

---

Lines of code I've attempted:

**Attempted to use `df.apply()`** - though through my searching, I don't think you can easily reference two columns in this manner...

```
    df['lat'] = df['lat'].apply(lambda x: x * -1 if (df['lat-dir'][x] == 'S'))
```

---

```
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        if (row['lat-dir'] == 'S'):
            df['lat'][i].apply(lambda x: x*-1)
```

For this, I get 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'apply' ?

---

**Attempted to use masking:**

```
    if( df['lon-dir'] == 'W'):
         df['lon'] * -1
```

---

But frankly, I'm stumped on what to do next regarding applying the mask.

EDIT:

`dfDate['lat'] = dfDate['lat'].apply(lambda row: row['lon'] * -1 , axis = 1 )`

Attempted this as well per comments.

Comment: Don’t use `iterrows()`. Could you share more of your code, and some data? Please see: [mcve]. In particular, I want to check the dtypes and the contents of the DataFrame. Also, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've added in how I pulled my data alongside a sample. Of note: I reformatted `lat` and `lon` to floats using the format `df['lat'] = df['lat'].astype(float)`, though I was getting errors in the compiler I used to make the sample dataframe. I am using jupyter notebook for the actual project.

Comment: Wait, were the errors before you castes to float, or did the conversion cause errors? What was the original dtype of the column?

Comment: Also, you write that the code is _roughly_ how you created the DataFrame. Why only _roughly_? The goal here is for anyone to be able to copy/paste a few things and be able to run the program in essentially the same conditions as you.

Comment: I ran all my code after converting to floats, the original dtypes of all the columns were unicode. I write roughly since the only change was shifting the dates to the index (which also works without a hitch in jupyter notebook, but not the compiler). I didn't know if shifting the index to dates would be relevant to calling the `lat` and `lon` columns.

Comment: Unicode? They were strings? How did you get the error _numpy.float64 object..._, then? What’s the output of `df.dtypes`, before and after? While it may not be causing any issues here, it might be worth considering dropping the Jupyter Notebook, at least for now. The global/shared state means that sometimes, code written in a plain py file which would error out, or in which the IDE could detect the problem, runs just fine in the notebook and produces confusing/nonsensical output.

Comment: (Continued) If you would rather stick to the notebook, you can just remember to run `%reset -f` from time to time, and when you’re having issues.

Comment: The reason your apply call failed is you need to apply it to the entire column/Series, not individual entries. So: `df['lat'].apply(lambda: ..., axis=1)`

Comment: If you're using Python 3.x (as you totally should be by now, end of 2019), then you don't need the `u'...'` everywhere, text is now unicode by default in 3.x. And if you're not using Python 3.x, you should switch over now, [2.x is being sunsetted Jan 1, 2020](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, by either of the following:

A) **using a vectorized mask**. `==` isn't vectorized; `.eq(...)` is. For a vectorized expression, use `dfDate['lon-dir'].eq('W')`. Then negate 'lon' column on those rows.

B) **using `apply()` row-wise**: `dfDate['lon'] = dfDate.apply(lambda row: ..., axis=1)`
 - and in your lambda selectively negate `row['lon']` based on value `row['lon-dir']`
 - the reason your `apply` call failed is you need to apply to the entire column/Series, not individual entries. So: `df['lat'].apply(lambda: ..., axis=1)`

`lat-dir`/`lon-dir` are essentially sign columns, you could convert them to +1/-1 when you read them in.

Code:

First some issues with your code that you'll want to fix:

1. **Don't use the u'...' notation**. Assuming you're using Python 3.x, don't need u'...', text is now unicode by default in 3.x. And if you're not using Python 3.x, you really should switch over now, 2.x is being sunsetted Jan 1, 2020.
2. Pass the JSON column names onto the dataframe, make your life easy:

   - `df.columns = j['fields']`
3. Reading in the JSON by passing `response.json()` into `pd.DataFrame.from_dict()` is a pain; your dataframe columns become  string/'object' rather than the float ones being converted to float. Ideally we should be using `pandas.read_json(..., dtype=...)` for this and other convenience reasons.
4. You're going to want to **convert the dtypes** (e.g. string -> float) on numeric columns, and that also automatically converts Python `None` ->  pandas/numpy `nan` (for the sake of the vectorized code we're going to write gracefully handling `nan` and not constantly throwing annoying `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'int'`). You can [do this with either `astype(...)`, `pd.to_numeric()` or `df.fillna(value=pd.np.nan, inplace=True)`
5. Really those nan entries are going to keep being a pain for multiple reasons listed below (e.g. integers keep getting coerced back to float), so **you'll probably want to drop or at least temporarily ignore the nan rows** by doing:

   - `df2 = df.dropna(how='any', inplace=False)` # probably not with `..., inplace=True`. Note that that preserves the row-indices, so you can always insert the result of prpcessing df2 back into df at the end. Read the `dropna` doc and figure out at what exact point you want to drop the nan's.
   - Note that 'vel' column actually has other nans which we want to ignore, you'll need to figure that out, or for now ignore them: e.g. do `df2 = df[['date','energy','impact-e','lat','lat-dir','lon','lon-dir']].dropna(how='any', inplace=False)`

## Solution

6. Several ways to translate the lat/lon-dir columns to +/-1 signs:

   A1) if you want the 'correct', nan-aware way which doesn't choke on nans...

```
    df2['lat'] = df2['lat-dir'].map({'N': +1, 'S': -1})
    df2['lon'] = df2['lon-dir'].map({'E': +1, 'W': -1})
```

```
A2) ...or a fast-and-dirty way:
```

```
    (-1) ** df2['lat-dir'].eq('S')
    (-1) ** df2['lon-dir'].eq('W')
```

B) But you can do this all in one row-wise `apply()` function:

```
def fixup_latlon_signs(row):
    row['lat'] = row['lat'] * (-1) ** (row['lat-dir'] == 'S')
    row['lon'] = row['lon'] * (-1) ** (row['lon-dir'] == 'W')
    return row

df2.apply(fixup_latlon_signs, axis=1)

# Then insert the non-NA rows we processed back into the parent dataframe:
df.update(df2)

# Strictly we can drop 'lat-dir','lon-dir' now...
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I believe I've formatted the question closer to an MCVE. Are you willing to delve more on the 
`dfDate['lon'] = dfDate.apply(lambda row: ..., axis=1)` option? I'm getting errors that axis is not an argument.

Comment: @LucienSethAñanso Can you include the exact code you tried, maybe as an edit to the OP?